# Need help solving the below mentioned equation.

Tags: polynomials

Consider $$a~q^x~+~b~y^x~+~c~z^x~= \text{constant}~.$$
Now, I have the values of $~q,~ y ,~$ and $~z~$ as well as the constant.

I need to solve the equation to obtain $~a,~ b ~$ and $~c~$ and the powers of $~q,~ y ,~$ and $~z~$ such that it satisfies the equation.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I guess that no closed form could be derived for such a problem. You may be able to solve it numerically only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to many variables and to little equations to find a unique solution. In this circumstance I would suggest taking $x=0$. I will assume without loss of generality that $q\neq0$ so we can take $a=\text{constant}$ and $b=c=0$.

Comment: The OP says that y and z are constants, not necessarily zero.

Comment: Sorry, bit of a typo.